# How do you install the NETTCPIP from Powershell 3.0 in Windows 7.0

Tags: windows-7, powershell-3.0

How do you install the new `NETTCPIP` from PowerShell 3.0 in Windows 7.0?

I've double checked what I've got installed with `$host.version` and it's showing as 3.0, so why aren't the new NET TCP/IP cmdlets showing ?

Comment: some cmdlets are only part of Windows 8 and not released with the Powershell 3.0 update for Windows 7.

Comment: @magicandre1981 ... please add this as an answer so I can acknowledge it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some [cmdlets are only part of Windows 8](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/08/17/weekend-scripter-understanding-powershell-in-windows-7.aspx) and not released with the Powershell 3.0 update for Windows 7.

Comment: thank you for the prompt response, much appreciated  :-)

Answer (score 0):

dowload module from :
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4308.popular-powershell-modules.aspx

extract folder to : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules .
nb : you can see auther the default location of PS modul folder py typing ($Env:PSModulePath ).

finally run this command to import module : Import-Module  -Name 
after type this command to see if your new modul has correctly imported :
get-module -all

Comment: That page doesn't have / no longer has NetTCPIP.